# Fabric.js scale group of objects

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to allow users to create "user libraries".  Basically on the main canvas they have the ability to add shapes (the shapes are loaded from svg strings) and then select multiple shapes and drag them to a separate canvas which will essentially take the shapes and create a new svg from that.  The new shape/group has to fit in a 48 x 48 box for thumbnail/dragging no matter the size of the original object group.

I have it working to where they're able to drag the shapes from one canvas to another, but for whatever reason when I try and output to a new svg the locations of the objects are really far off from where they were in the group when they were dragged onto the new canvas.

This is the code I have right now to get the svg string:

```
var group = [];
var shape = new fabric.Group(group);
$.each(activeGroup._objects, function (index, item) {
    group.push(item);
});
svgString = shape.toSVG();
```

and this is what I have to load it up:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function (objects, options) {
    var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
    loadedObjects.set({
        left: left, top: top, hasControls: false, selectable: true, originX: 'left', originY: 'top', height: 50, width: 50
    });
    canvas.add(loadedObjects);
}, function (item, object) {
    object.set('id', item.getAttribute('id'));
    group.push(object);
});
```

Here's one example:

Before - [image]
After - [image]

Sometimes the shapes stay where they were, but if one is scaled up (as is the case with the circle below) it gets misplaced.

Sorry for the long post, but here's a summary of my issues:
1) Scaling groups down to 48x48, currently they're just staying the same size.  I've tried scaleToHeight and scaleToWidth and other width setting stuff, but nothing changes.
2) misplaced objects from where they were prior to toSVG().